# How to access pixel value fast in C++ with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I looked up some tutorials on accessing pixel values in C++ with OpenCV. For an example of modifying every pixel value, using .ptr is faster than using .at

I realize that how you calculate the new value for assignment also influence your performance, but I wonder if using .ptr is alway faster than .at?

Even if what I do is comparing a pixel with its neighbor pixels?

I'm writing a code to find out if a pixel were maximum/minimum around its 8 neighbor pixels and other 18 more pixels from two different Gaussian-blurred (different sigma) images. (Yes, for SIFT) I'm currently using .at to access pixel value, and I can tell the code takes some time to run (Cuz there are many images need to go through the same process). I wonder if using .ptr will make performance better or not.

Comment: Adding to @bachinblack 's answer, try to avoid manual pixel manipulation, instead try using OpenCV's native functions as much as you can. Those functions are highly optimized. But if you *have* to process pixel data, you can use parallel_for to speed up your code, provided of course that your algorithm can parallelized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/db/da5/tutorial_how_to_scan_images.html) says that the *pointers method* is the fastest in every case. The other methods are only safer. 
It also says that the `.at()` method is the most time consuming, this should explain your lack in performances

Comment: No need to couch your response with the last sentence, the docs do indeed say what you've written. Similarly, your opinion isn't needed on pointers vs iterators---again, the docs from the library specify that concretely, so it's not *only* your opinion :). Great answer and welcome to Stack! Though I'd recommend using links to the [more recent OpenCV version docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/db/da5/tutorial_how_to_scan_images.html).